# Can't do anything inside my custom event

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have a custom event that I want to use to display a previously hidden element on my page.

**ASPX:**

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/EditSync.ascx" TagPrefix="IP" TagName="EditSync" %>

<asp:Content ID="main" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">

//Some unrelated controls

    <fieldset id="fsEditPlugin" runat="server" class="inputForm" style="width:450px;" visible="false">
        <IP:EditSync id="ctlEditSync" runat="server" />
    </fieldset>
</asp:Content>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ctlDelivery.EditPlugin += new EventHandler(onEditPlugin);
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //Some more unrelated things
    }
}

public void onEditPlugin(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(((ip.Controls.EditPluginEventArgs)e).type);
    fsEditPlugin.Visible = true;
}
```

the debug-message is displayed. I can place breakpoints in the event-handler and they are reached, but no matter what I try I can't manipulate the page from my event handler. The fsEditPlugin is not a child of anything else that is hidden. Some things I've tried:

```
//I've tried this:
<fieldset id="fsEditPlugin" runat="server" class="inputForm" style="width:450px; display:none;">
//code behind:
fsEditPlugin.Style.Add("display", "inline");

//I've tried this:
<fieldset id="fsEditPlugin" runat="server" class="inputForm" style="width:450px;">
</fieldset>
//Code behind:
fsEditPlugin.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("TEST"));
```

Nothing seems to work. There isn't anything in my Page_Load that should interfere with the controls.

The event is being fired from another child web user control. So when I press a button in another child web user control I want to make the EditSync-control to become visible.

Comment: That is not your entire code I guess, since you never register `onEditPlugin` here. Also, what is `IP:EditSync`?

Comment: If you set the default value of fsEditPlugin.Visible to true, can you see it, or can you still not see it then?

Comment: @PatrickHofman give me a sec and I'll add more code

Comment: @StrahBehry No, that doesn't do anything. It's visible from the start and it's visible after the event has been caught.

Comment: Is the control you want to manipulate in an updatepanel?

Comment: @AndrewMorton no, but the control that's fireing the event is in one

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks! This comment helped me solve the problem! I posted an answer explaining what happened if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally managed to fix the problem!

The problem was that my button that fired the event was from within a update panel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <IP:Delivery id="ctlDelivery" runat="server" /> <% /* this is a web user control */ %>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I solved this by adding the following line to the Page_Load of ctlDelivery:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(btnEdit); //btnEdit is the button that fires my custom event.
```

shoutout to EvilDr and his [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12973855/1323785)