# webforms all children performing async postback even when updatemode set to conditional

Tags: asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

I have an update panel with UpdateMode set to conditional, and childrenastriggers set to false, but all the controls in the panel are performing async postbacks...

```
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="pnlUpdateProgress" DisplayAfter="1" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            Update in progress...
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="pnlUpdate" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDoNothing" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    <div runat="server" clientidmode="Static" id="divList">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDoNothing" Text="Do nothing" OnClick="Unnamed_Click" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSync" Text="Sync" OnClick="btnSync_Click" />
        <br />
        <div class="items_bought_table">
            <table style="width: 100%; padding-bottom:24px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align: left;">Description</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litList" />
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        
    <br />
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litDebugText" />
    </div>

 <div runat="server" clientidmode="Static" id="divEdit">
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="txtEditID" />

        <asp:Literal ID="litEditList" runat="server">

        </asp:Literal>
        
        <ul>
        <li class="full_width pt_10">
            Your Product: <em><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litEditProductName" /></em>
        </li>
    </ul>

 </div>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here both btnSync and btnDoNoting are performing async postbacks, where I would expect only btnDoNothing to post back async, btnSync should perform a full postback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @wazz stated in their answer, this is normal behavior in an update panel. To make a full back you need to make a "PostBackTrigger" as documented in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2545541/1203540) question.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
      ...
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
      <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="myFullPostBackControlID" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

AsyncPostBackTrigger only sets controls that are outside of the panel.

> Controls on the page *outside of an update panel* can refresh an UpdatePanel control by defining them as triggers. Triggers are defined by using the AsyncPostBackTrigger element.

Controls that postback will always postback. I *think* the `ChildrenAsTriggers="false"` won't stop the postbacks - it will just stop the content from updating.